# Return the dtype for an element in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array with heterogeneous dtypes called **saturn**, output as follows:

```
>>> print(saturn.data.dtype)
[('datetime_jd', '<f8'), ('e', '<f8'), ('p', '<f8'), ('incl', '<f8'), ('node', '<f8'), ('argper', '<f8'), ('Tp', '<f8'), ('meananomaly', '<f8'), ('trueanomaly', '<f8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('Q', '<f8'), ('period', '<f8'), ('targetname', 'O'), ('H', '<f8'), ('G', '<f8')]

>>> print(saturn.data)
[ ( 2469807.5,  0.05562189,  8.98453,  2.4902161,  113.50835237,  339.33530396,  2474316.18403117,  208.54216243,  205.67358555,  9.51369999,  10.04286998,  29.34020819, 'Saturn (699)',  nan,  nan)]
```

Now I would like to now assign each item in the array to the **saturn** object as an attribute, using something like:

```
for key, value in saturn.data.items():
    setattr(saturn, key, value)
```

Or even a dictionary would be useful, using something like:

```
saturn.data_dictionary={}
for d in saturn.data:
    saturn.data_dictionary[d.dtype]=d
```

So the question is: **How do I return the dtype from a Numpy array element?**

*Background for info:*
The array was downloaded from the [JPL Horizons system](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) using the [callhorizons](http://callhorizons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) package.

Cheers!

Comment: Um, everything in your structured array looks like a 64-bit, little-endian float... except `'targetname', 'O'` which is `object` dtype... But I don't understand why you even need the `dtype`, and would be better off using Python types in an object anyway...

Comment: Or for that matter, why you are even trying to assign them as attributes on the `numpy.ndarray` saturn object... it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what I eventually want to get to is: saturn.datetime_jd=2469807.5; saturn.e=0.05562189; saturn.p=8.98453; etc.

Comment: But **why on earth would you want to do that**?  And why do you care about the `dtype` in that case anyway? You already have all that information, stored nice and compactly, and easily accessible with essentially the same interface: `sature[0]['e']` for example...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Maybe because it is nicer to type `saturn.e` instead of `saturn.data['e']` or `saturn.data[0]['e']`?  And it allows tab completion of the attributes in an interactive shell such as ipython.  Namespaces are a honkin' great idea and all that.

Comment: the saturn object will eventually be a subclass with a number of methods based on various attributes (e, a, incl, etc).

Comment: A subclass of what? What do you mean the object will be a subclass?
 That doesn't make sense to me.  Anyway, you can always use `element_from_array.dtype` to get the dtype, unless the object you access from the array is a not a `numpy` object, because it is `object` dtype, i.e. a plain Python object, in whichcase `element.dtype` will throw an AttributeError. But again, **you already know the dtypes**.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser well, then you should be using a normal Python object, and not a structured `numpy.ndarray`. In any event, *knowing the dtypes still doesn't make any sense*. You don't *need to know the dtypes* to assign them as attributes. And anyway, again, you just use `element_from_array.dtype`, and be careful for the case where that throws an AttributeError, in which case you know it is `dtype=object`

Comment: Using field names as dictionary key or attribute name makes more sense than than the `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj agreed, but unfortunately the data is coming in as a structured array from the callhorizons package.

Answer (score 0):

So to make structured array from your example (having defined `nan=np.nan`):

```
In [165]: dt = np.dtype([('datetime_jd', '<f8'), ('e', '<f8'), ('p', '<f8'), ('i
     ...: ncl', '<f8'), ('node', '<f8'), ('argper', '<f8'), ('Tp', '<f8'), ('mea
     ...: nanomaly', '<f8'), ('trueanomaly', '<f8'), ('a', '<f8'), ('Q', '<f8'),
     ...:  ('period', '<f8'), ('targetname', 'O'), ('H', '<f8'), ('G', '<f8')])

In [166]: data = np.array([ ( 2469807.5,  0.05562189,  8.98453,  2.4902161,  113
     ...: .50835237,  339.33530396,  2474316.18403117,  208.54216243,  205.67358
     ...: 555,  9.51369999,  10.04286998,  29.34020819, 'Saturn (699)',  nan,  n
     ...: an)], dtype=dt)
```

And to make things a bit more realistic, concatenate several instances.  After all what's the use of a structured array with shape (1,)?

```
In [167]: data1 = np.concatenate([data,data,data])
```

Normal field access is with a dictionary like indexing, with 1 value for each record:

```
In [168]: data1['H']
Out[168]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
In [169]: data1['period']
Out[169]: array([ 29.34020819,  29.34020819,  29.34020819])
```

I can make a recarray of the same, and access fields with attribute syntax:

```
In [170]: dataR = data1.view(np.recarray)
In [171]: dataR.node
Out[171]: array([ 113.50835237,  113.50835237,  113.50835237])
```

Just show that this is a view:

```
In [172]: dataR.H = [1,2,3]
In [173]: data1['H']
Out[173]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

So if `saturn.data` is the structured array, then

```
saturn.dataR = saturn.data.view(np.recarray)
```

would let you access value(s) with

```
saturn.dataR.H
```

To create attributes like `saturn.H`, I can see doing something like:

Use `argparse` to create an object that takes attribute assignment (just happens to be class that I know works well for this (in Py3):

```
In [186]: import argparse
In [187]: ns = argparse.Namespace()
In [188]: for name in dt.names:
     ...:     setattr(ns, name, data[name])

In [189]: ns
Out[189]: Namespace(G=array([ nan]), H=array([ nan]), Q=array([ 10.04286998]), Tp=array([ 2474316.18403117]), a=array([ 9.51369999]), argper=array([ 339.33530396]), datetime_jd=array([ 2469807.5]), e=array([ 0.05562189]), incl=array([ 2.4902161]), meananomaly=array([ 208.54216243]), node=array([ 113.50835237]), p=array([ 8.98453]), period=array([ 29.34020819]), targetname=array(['Saturn (699)'], dtype=object), trueanomaly=array([ 205.67358555]))
In [190]: ns.argper
Out[190]: array([ 339.33530396])
```

Iterate on names as well if you want to make a dictionary of values:

```
In [199]: saturn_dict = {name: data[name] for name in dt.names}
In [200]: saturn_dict
Out[200]: 
{'G': array([ nan]),
 'H': array([ nan]),
 'Q': array([ 10.04286998]),
 'Tp': array([ 2474316.18403117]),
 'a': array([ 9.51369999]),
 'argper': array([ 339.33530396]),
 'datetime_jd': array([ 2469807.5]),
 'e': array([ 0.05562189]),
 'incl': array([ 2.4902161]),
 'meananomaly': array([ 208.54216243]),
 'node': array([ 113.50835237]),
 'p': array([ 8.98453]),
 'period': array([ 29.34020819]),
 'targetname': array(['Saturn (699)'], dtype=object),
 'trueanomaly': array([ 205.67358555])}
```

or for a single record of the structured array:

```
In [201]: saturn_dict = {name: data[0][name] for name in dt.names}
In [202]: saturn_dict
Out[202]: 
{'G': nan,
 'H': nan,
 'Q': 10.042869980000001,
 'Tp': 2474316.1840311699,
 'a': 9.5136999899999992,
 'argper': 339.33530395999998,
 'datetime_jd': 2469807.5,
 'e': 0.05562189,
 'incl': 2.4902161,
 'meananomaly': 208.54216242999999,
 'node': 113.50835237,
 'p': 8.9845299999999995,
 'period': 29.340208189999998,
 'targetname': 'Saturn (699)',
 'trueanomaly': 205.67358555000001}
```

and if you want to collect dtype info as well:

```
In [203]: saturn_dict = {name: (data[0][name],data[name].dtype) for name in dt.n
     ...: ames}
In [204]: saturn_dict
Out[204]: 
{'G': (nan, dtype('float64')),
 'H': (nan, dtype('float64')),
 'Q': (10.042869980000001, dtype('float64')),
 'Tp': (2474316.1840311699, dtype('float64')),
 ...
```